# Whatsapp status with scoped storage on android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, storage, whatsapp

I am working on whats-app status saver app, i don't understand how i can make it work on android 11. As storage all storage access got restricted and google rejected my update due to use of All files access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

But i tested another app, which is working fine and even saving files at root directory too. This app ask for this permission [Allow access to photo, media and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVTD8.jpg)
and when i check permissions in app setting it says app has access to [management of all files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysYrA.jpg). Even app has all files permission never show me [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuWYg.png) to get full files access.

Comment: Which another app are you talking about?

Comment: Further you did not tell why a 'whatsapp status saver app' needs access to storage.

Comment: If you are using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission you need to declare permission and submit app for approval before uploading it  to play store. 
[link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en&visit_id=637673021709653523-3503487402&rd=1)
Declaration form [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=en)

Comment: https://github.com/GauthamAsir/WhatsApp_Status_Saver, Whatsapp has moved its status directory to `/Android/media/com.whatsapp.android/Pictures/Statuses` which can be accessed

Comment: @blackapps checked this app from playstore working fine on android 11 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=statussaver.deleted.messages.savevidieos and i need storage access to save status at root directory as i am doing in android 10 and that other also saving files at root directory.

Comment: @NitishChaudhary yes, fill this form also but still update got rejected.

Comment: @gtxtreme yes, already check this repo. This build also getting all files access and my update got rejected due to this permission.

Comment: can anyone tell me how that other app getting all files access?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-all-files-access-permission . Does your app come under this criteria? I don't think so

Comment: @gtxtreme yes, i agree did you check images i linked? how the other apps are getting all files access?

Comment: It's probably because they are already there on the PlayStore, maybe they are not allowing new apps with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` unless they are under the mentioned categories

Comment: may be, then how i can get files form Statuses folder according to google docs it is part of shared storage but status folder it hidden. Can read it using Media Store ?

Comment: `s checked this app from playstore` I asked for a name. You still did not mention that apps name.

Comment: @blackapps app name "Dowload Status - Status Saver App", i also put app link in comment above please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user to pick up the WhatsApp directory and then you have access to the directory tree as @blackapps noted.

```
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker when it loads.
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);

    startActivityForResult(intent, your-request-code);
}
```

Access restrictions:
On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, you cannot use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to request access to the following directories:
• The root directory of the internal storage volume.
• The root directory of each SD card volume that the device manufacturer considers to be reliable, regardless of whether the card is emulated or removable. A reliable volume is one that an app can successfully access most of the time.
• The Download directory.
Furthermore, on Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, you cannot use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to request that the user select individual files from the following directories:
• The Android/data/ directory and all subdirectories.
• The Android/obb/ directory and all subdirectories.

Luckily, the Android/media directory does not fall under this restriction so you can ask the user to pick the Android/media/com.whatsapp directory to access all WhatsApp media including images, videos and status.
To learn more, you can visit [Access documents and other files from shared storage  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#java)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Storage Access Framework to let the user pick the required directory.

```
ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
```

Comment: i don't want user to pick a directory, just want to retrieve status files from whats-app status directory.

Comment: You let the user pick the  whats-app status directory was what i suggested. After that you can retrieve files. If you do not have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE then this is your only possibility.

Comment: agree, did you check the other app i mention? how that app is getting all files access with single permission may be there is some other permission i need.

Comment: No i did not check that. And will not do so too ;-)